# DLL lazy loading

Tags: c#, lazy-loading, class-library

I have complex .NET class library is dependent on several other .NET class libraries, but not all of them are used in every situation. Is there any way to mark them as 'Lazy loading', so I can delete it from folder if I know it is not used at all?

Comment: Normally, assemblies are lazily loaded but you seem to need *assurance* of that fact. Good question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All assemblies are always loaded on demand. If you remove an assembly from a folder, the application will work until the point where it needs to load that assembly.

Comment: But when exactly does a "demand situation" occur? Maybe it is *before* code from it is executed the first time.

Comment: A demand situation usually occurs when a type from that assembly needs to be loaded. And yes, it happens before the code is actually executed. (What I am nearly sure of is that, before a method can be run, all the types referenced by that method must be loaded - e.g. if you put a method `object GetIfAvailable(bool isAvailable) { if (isAvailable) return new Unavailable(); }` - the method will not even run if the `Unavailable` type is not found, even if it is not actually used, by calling it with a `false` parameter.)

Comment: @JeanHominal, good answer. I tested it, and it really works as you described. This behavior is exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Let's hope it really is that simple. If not, the OP's app will break at random points in the program.

Comment: Well, I would certainly not do what the OP does without a rearchitecturing of the "complex .NET class library" into multiple small libraries with well-defined sets of dependencies.

Comment: even if you redesign it, you have the same issue. You either need lazy loading or dynamic loading.

Comment: to clarify this answer, the lazy loading is done at the Method level (not class or a lower level. If you use Try/Catch to detect, you must put it around the call to the method that causes loading, not within the method itself.