# Loading dll's on demand

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I have a section of code which looks like this:

```
using OracleDll;
using TeradataDll;

...
private void Foo(){

if(clientProvider == "Oracle")
{
//code using the Oracle assembly
}

if(clientProvider == "Teradata")
{
// code using the Teradata assembly
}
}
```

How can I write this code in such a way that if I know that only the branch with Oracle will be used, then I can forget about deploying the Teradatadll?

Comment: did you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362368/loading-dlls-at-runtime-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: I was thinking more about some lazing loading then reflection. I know about the reflection method but I am looking for something else.

Comment: If you are interested in deployment, then look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862777/dll-lazy-loading

Comment: Lazy loading can be done via `Assembly.Load` at runtime. Isn't that lazy enough?